# PlayN skeleton project html module can't find core module in maven?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, playn

Based on the PlayN [Getting Started wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted) I created a skeleton project (called GuiPoc) in eclipse.  I managed to make the guipoc-html project compile successfully (with `Google -> GWT Compile`), and eventually `Run as -> Web Application`.  I tried using `mvn gae:run` from the guipoc/html directory (in cygwin) as per the wiki, and got the following output:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GuiPoc HTML 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:run (default-cli) @ guipoc-html >>>
[WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain.mynamespace:guipoc-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.619s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 01 20:05:29 VET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project guipoc-html: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydomain.mynamespace:guipoc-html:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.mydomain.mynamespace:guipoc-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**Actual Question:**
I don't understand why it's looking for the dependency in the system repository instead of the local directory.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to change something in my pom.xml files?  Create a settings.xml in my C:\Users\MyName.m2 directory and set something there?

Here is the content of guipoc/html/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mydomain.mynamespace</groupId>
    <artifactId>guipoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>guipoc-html</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>GuiPoc HTML</name>

  <properties>
    <gwt.module>com.mydomain.mynamespace.GuiPoc</gwt.module>
    <gwt.name>guipoc</gwt.name>
    <!-- Desired Google App Engine SDK version -->
    <gae.version>1.6.0</gae.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mydomain.mynamespace</groupId>
      <artifactId>guipoc-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
      <artifactId>playn-html</artifactId>
      <version>${playn.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildCommand>
              <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
            </buildCommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
            <projectnature>com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.gaeNature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
        <dependencies>
          <!--
            Declare explicit dependency on gae-runtime here,
            so we can specify the App Engine SDK version
          -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the content of guipoc/core/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mydomain.mynamespace</groupId>
    <artifactId>guipoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>guipoc-core</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>GuiPoc Core</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
      <artifactId>playn-core</artifactId>
      <version>${playn.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
      <!-- include the source files in our main jar for use by GWT -->
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
      </resource>
      <!-- and continue to include our standard resources -->
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the content of guipoc/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
    <artifactId>playn-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.mydomain.mynamespace</groupId>
  <artifactId>guipoc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>GuiPoc Metaproject</name>

  <properties>
    <playn.version>1.0.3</playn.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>java</module>
    <module>html</module>
    <module>android</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Maven is not too smart about multimodule projects. A standard PlayN project (including yours) has the following module structure:

```
top
+- core
+- html (depends on core)
+- java (depends on core)
+- android, flash, etc.
```

When you are in the `top` directory, and you invoke Maven, it reads all of the submodule POMs and "knows" about all of them and will properly set up classpaths so that they see the appropriate `classes` directory when compiling and running.

But if you go into, say, the `html` directory and invoke Maven there, it no longer "knows" about all of the submodules. All it knows about is the `html` POM and when it sees a dependency for anything else (like the `core` module in this case) it goes through the standard dependency resolution process, which is:

1. Check the local Maven repository `~/.m2/repository`.
2. Check the repositories explicitly specified in the POMs.
3. Check Maven Central.

When you have a situation where you want to run a command in one of your submodule projects, you have to arrange to do it from the top-level project. This is why testing from the command line involves running `mvn test -P test-java` or `mvn test -P test-html` from the top-level directory, rather than just cd-ing into the `java` or `html` directory and running `mvn test`.

Unfortunately, the tricks that we use to make it possible to test the Java or HTML submodule from the command line don't work with `gae:run`. So in this case, you have to work around Maven's limitations by first installing your project artifacts into your local Maven repository before invoking `gae:run` (and indeed, doing this every time you want to test using `gae:run`. This is accomplished like so:

```
cd top
mvn install
cd html
mvn gae:run
```

It would be great if Maven were smart enough to detect that it was being run in a submodule directory and automatically resolve sibling dependencies in the same way it would if you invoked Maven from the top-level project directory. Alas, smart is an adjective that's rarely applicable when talking about Maven.

Comment: This eventually worked after some other hoops involving installing the correct Android SDK version and running `mvn gae:unpack` to download the appropriate appengine SDK.  Thanks much.